# Linux redirect to multiple targets

Tags: c, linux, bash

How could I redirect output to multiple targets, say stdout, file, socket and so?

say, i have a system here and connected to some network. When it fails, the guy supervises it via ssh should be able to notice it, or the GUI client should receive the error info, or, in the worst case, we can still find something in the log.

or even more targets. Atomicity may or may not need to be guaranteed.

so how to do this in bash and/or in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect with `tee` to any number of files and to any commands too, like:

```
seq 50 | tee copy1 copy2 >((echo Original linecount: $(grep -c ''))>&2) | grep '9'
```

what prints:

```
9
19
29
39
49
Original linecount: 50   #printed to stderr
```

or

```
seq 50 | tee copy1 copy2 >((echo Original linecount: $(grep -c ''))>&2) | grep '9' | wc -l
```

what prints the count of numbers containing digit 9 in first 50 numbers, while make two copyes of the original sequence...

```
Original linecount: 50   #stderr
       5
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the "tee" command.

Comment: even multiple targets? i want to pass the output to the socket too and potentially everything that can receive data, named or not.

Comment: You can tee to multiple outputs, e.g. [commandA] | tee [commandB] | tee [commandC] | ... | tee [commandD] | commandE

Comment: will that damage the performance too much? it looks like keeping forking processes to me.

Comment: `tee` accepts multiple file names at the command line: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html

Comment: @mafso sounds good. so can i do something special in C instead of for looping a bunch of fd's?

Comment: I've just looked at the coreutils sources. The `tee` command does nothing different than reading into a `BUFSIZ`-sized buffer and writing to each stream in a loop. So I think, the answer is no.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr No, that's what you'd do, a loop.